welcome-file-list y session-config en el archivo web.xml, no se comportan debidamente
tengo el siguiente problema con estas reglas.
Dentro del archivo web.xml de mi aplicación java, trabajo con las siguientes 2 reglas.
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>

Hasta donde logro entender, una es el archivo de bienvenida, y el otro, el tiempo de sesión máximo de 30 minutos.
Sucede, que al momento de

Acabar la sesión, se trata de redirigir al usuario
Al entrar a una ruta que no existe, debiese retornar al archivo welcome.

Pero en estos dos casos, al momento de redireccionar, me genera una ruta con el archivo welcome.xhtml, que no existe. Por ejemplo /negocio/welcome.xhtml.
Verifique que mis archivos estuvieran bien ubicados, y que las reglas estuviesen bien escritas. Pero me sigue produciendo rutas, con el welcome.xhtml, que son no existentes:
ejemplo del error en la web: /negocio/prestador/welcome.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

¿Cómo tienes organizadas las carpetas y qué archivos tienes en WebContent?

No tengo webcontent, tengo webapp, hay diferencias en ello ?
welcome, está en la raíz, es decir dentro de webapp. La caché cada tanto me da problemas, pero no es eso en este caso, ya que la ruta generada, la puedo ver en diferentes lados, servidor y computadores locales.

No creo que haya problemas en que se llame webapp. Pero, ¿qué archivos tienes declarados en webapp?

dentro de webapp esta mi directorio, los archivos principales son index.xhtml y welcome.xhtml. También ahi mismo esta la carpeta de negocio y dentro prestador. Ahora, dentro de prestador, no existe ni debe existir un welcome nuevamente. Había entendido que el declarado en el web.xml, era el que estaba dentro de webapp simplemente.

Revisa esta respuesta, verifica que tienes declarado el patrón <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> en web.xml.

El directorio es correcto, incluida la propuesta de esa respuesta. Tengo url-pattern, pero esta dentro de servlet mapping, dado que es una app con faces servlet.
